# Save and read vector of vectors of Mat in OpenCV using Filestrage

Tags: opencv, vector, file-storage

I'd like to ask for help with reading and writing vector of vectors of Mats using opencv's filestorage.

I use this function to write:

```
Template<typename _Tp>inline void writeFileNodeList(FileStorage& fs, const string& name,const vector<_Tp>& items) 
{
        // typedefs
        //typedef typename vector<_Tp>::const_iterator constVecIterator;
        vector<Mat>::iterator it;
        // write the elements in item to fs
        fs << name << "[";
        for (it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it) {
            fs << *it;
        }
        fs << "]";
}
```

and this to read:

```
template<typename _Tp>inline void readFileNodeList(const FileNode& fn, vector<_Tp>& result) {
    if (fn.type() == FileNode::SEQ) {
        //vector<Mat>::iterator it;
        for (FileNodeIterator it = fn.begin(); it != fn.end();it++) {
            _Tp item;
            it >> item;
            result.push_back(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Code for writing works badly and that one for reading is not possible to build. 
I'm actually totally desparete, I have used all I can imagine. I have looked here for same sample codes but none of them didn't worked for me. 
Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem by myself.

Here's the code:

```
    void writeFileNodeList(FileStorage& fs, const string& name,vector<vector<Mat>> items) 
    {
        int IDs=items.size();
        // typedefs
        fs << name << "{";
        for (int i=0;i<IDs;i++)
        {
            stringstream ss;
            string s;
            string a;
            a="ID-label";
            ss << (i+1);
            s = ss.str();
            a+=s;

            fs  << a << "[";

            for (int j=0;j<items[i].size();j++)
            {
                fs<<items[i][j];        
            }   
            fs <<"]";
        }
        fs << "}";

}
```

> and here is the part for reading xml back

```
vector<vector<Mat>> readFileNodeList2(const FileNode& fn) 
{   
    //cout <<fn.name() <<endl;
    //cout <<fn.size() <<endl;
    vector<vector<Mat>> output;
    //cout << fn.isMap() << endl;

    for (int ID=0;ID<fn.size();ID++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        string s;
        string a;
        a="ID-label";
        ss << (ID+1);
        s = ss.str();
        a+=s;
        FileNode temp_ID;
        temp_ID=fn[a];
        vector<Mat> one_person_patrerns;
        readFileNodeList(temp_ID,one_person_patrerns);
        output.push_back(one_person_patrerns);
    }
    return output;
}

template<typename _Tp>inline void readFileNodeList(const FileNode& fn,vector<_Tp>& result) 
{
    if (fn.type() == FileNode::SEQ) {
        for (FileNodeIterator it = fn.begin(); it != fn.end();) {
            _Tp item;
            it >> item;
            result.push_back(item);
        }
    }
}
```